# List of GNOME 3 applets and gnome-shell extensions

Tags: software-recommendation, gnome

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 on one of my systems and I am using gnome-shell. I miss some tools for showing weather, unread mail, net speed, cpu temp, and system monitor.

Are there similar indicators as presented in [What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/list-of-application-indicators)?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/official-gnome-shell-extensions.html lists some.

Comment: This should be a Comunnity Wiki. and just as you did on the Weather extension, you can list one per answer plus some screenshots not just the link.

Comment: Thank you, actually I wanted this to be Community Wiki, but did not find a way how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Weather

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/install-gnome-shell-weather-extension.html