# List of Gnome-Shell 3.2 Extension

Tags: 11.10, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of GNOME 3 applets and gnome-shell extensions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63117/list-of-gnome-3-applets-and-gnome-shell-extensions)

I recently upgraded to 11.10, and am using `gnome-shell` 3.2.

I haven't been able to find a comprehensive list of extensions that work with version 3.2 of gnome-shell.

If you know of any please list out any extensions with links so that they can be found in one place.

Answer (score 1):

### [Hamster Shell Extension](https://github.com/tbaugis/hamster-shell-extension)

**Category**: *Productivity*

Clean gnome shell extension for [hamster](http://projecthamster.wordpress.com/).

[image]